# How can a child class' overriden method be accessed statically?

Tags: java, static, abstract-class

So I already know it's impossible to have a static method in an abstract class. However, is there a way for an overridden method in its child class to be accessed without instantiating it?

For example, let's say I have two classes, an abstract class element and its child class Hydrogen, as shown below. This assumes that I will have multiple similar classes, such as Helium, Boron, etc. which are all child classes of Element.

```
public abstract class Element {
    public abstract double getMolarMass();
}

public final Hydrogen extends Element {
    @Override
    public double getMolarMass() {
        return 1.008;
    }
}
```

How would I be able to be able to call the getMolarMass method without having to instantiate the Hydrogen object?

Comment: But that would defeat the purpose of an override...

Comment: "So I already know it's impossible to have a static method in an abstract class" - no it's not

Comment: You _can_ have a static method in an abstract class. It just can't be abstract itself.

Comment: "However, is there a way for an overridden method in its child class to be accessed without instantiating it?" No, it's not possible to call *any* instance method without an instance.

Comment: why should it be static? molar mass is per element. it shoudn't be static.

Comment: @OfirWinegarten I was planning to have an array of elements, so that I could call Element.getMolarMass for each cell to get the total molar mass of the array

Comment: Where is the array? how do you expect to call it? please edit your post to better describe your scenario and use case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve is creating an Enum. There's an enum keyword allowing you to directly do what you seemingly want to achieve.

An enum is effectively a final class with several public static final member variables, which hold references to instances of the class.

```
enum Element
{
    Hydrogen(1.0),
    Helium(2.0),
    ...;

    private double mass;

    private Element(double masss)
    {
        this.mass = mass;
    }

    public double getMasss()
    {
        return mass;
    }
}
```

You can access the fields directly, e.g.:

```
Element e = Element.Helium;
System.out.println("The mass of " + e + " is " + e.getMass());
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thanks

Comment: Just would like to say thank you again. I've managed to fix my problem with enums. Turns out I was looking in the wrong direction.

Comment: Not quite, as Java's enums are a built-in mechanism for implementing a pattern named "type-safe enums", once popularized by Josh Bloch in his book Effective java before language support with java 5. Apart from the, in this case, unnecessary subclassing, you probably were on track to eventually find that pattern yourself :)

Comment: Btw., in some less usual cases you actually want an type safe enum with subclasses as the types of its fields, in which case you need to go back to the manual implementation, as built-in enums do not support that :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you want to have access to constants in your subclasses while at the same time allowing for polymorphic behavior involving these values. You can have a constant and also return it from your method:

```
public final class Hydrogen extends Element {
  public static final double MOLAR_MASS = 1.008;

  @Override
  public double getMolarMass() {
    return MOLAR_MASS;
  }
}
```

Then, you can access the constant statically: `Hydrogen.MOLAR_MASS`.

Comment: Except there's language support for the much cleaner typesafe enum pattern since Java 5, in the form of enums :)

Comment: @yeoman: it all depends on the situation, both solutions can be clean

Comment: I guess I just don't like the redundancy of there being a public constant and a dynamic way to access it, so close together... Of course, having to say Hydrogen.Instance.getMolarMass() would be wordier that just saying Hydrogen.MOLAR_MASS. With an enum, the redundancy goes away, but access is longer, too: Element.Hydrogen.getMolarMass(). I personally dislike redundancy more then verbosity, but of course, tastes differ :)

Comment: A more suitable design invariably depends on the bigger picture, not just on the specific question that was asked. I'm merely offering an alternative, which might be preferable to an enum in certain situations. Think different isotopes and even molecules...

Answer (score 0):

if the method is not static then you can not call it statically,
on the other hand overriding static methods makes no sense and is not allowed in java...